# Searching in Friends of Friends C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am developing a tool to search friends for a member whose City is same as the member and is not already a friend of the member. So for example if Mark is living in New Jersey and so is Nancy but Mark and Nancy are not friends at the moment but Mark is friends with Paul and Paul is friends with Alex and Alex is friends with Nancy so my search should return path from Mark to Nancy as
"Mark -- Paul -- Alex -- Nancy("New Jersey")"

Yes keeping in mind there can be more Members living in City but not Friends so need to show path to those as well. Meaning it can be a collection of paths.

I have following classes at the moments in which I have self referencing many to many relationships.

```
public class Friend
{
    public Member Member1 { get; set; }

    public Member Member2 { get; set; }

    public int Member1Id { get; set; }
   
    public int Member2Id { get; set; }
     
}

public class Member
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string City {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Friend> MemberFriends { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Friend> MemberFriendsOf { get; set; }
}
```

in ApplicationDbContext

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Friend>()
            .HasKey(f => new { f.Member1Id, f.Member2Id });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Friend>()
            .HasOne(f => f.Member1)
            .WithMany(f=>f.MemberFriends)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.Member1Id)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Friend>()
            .HasOne(f => f.Member2)
            .WithMany(f=>f.MemberFriendsOf)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.Member2Id);
```

Using EF Core 3.1
Thanks

Comment: How many degrees of separation do you plan on searching

Comment: Have you already tried implementing it? Must the code be translatable to SQL?

Comment: @CaiusJard what about 2 degrees at the moment?

Comment: @Tvde1 yes I have tried but no luck yet. "Must the code be translatable to SQL?" I didn't get it. But if this means that creating models and adding to MS SQL DB then yes because members and friends information needs to be stored.

Comment: The query about whether the code must be translatable essentially asks if it is the DB that should make connections between people

Comment: Get your person and then get all the people that they know from city X. Then get all the people that those people know from city X. Look for any member of this second list that is a member of the first

Comment: @CaiusJard code example please?